# Keep mousePressed active after one click

Tags: java, mouse

So what I want to do is after one click is keep the mousePressed method 'on' even though im not holding it down myself. Then after another click it will turn it 'off'

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // save coord x,y when mouse is pressed
            oldX = e.getX();
            oldY = e.getY();
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            // coord x,y when drag mouse
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();

            if (g2 != null) {
                // draw oval if g2 context not null
                g2.drawOval(oldX, oldY, width, height);
                g2.fillOval(oldX, oldY, width, height);

                // refresh draw area to repaint
                repaint();

                // store current coords x,y as olds x,y
                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: use a boolean field..to understand if it wwas clicked out not...

Comment: Set a Boolean flag (or track the number of clicks and use modular maths) and monitor the mouseMoved event instead

Answer (score 1):

1. Handle the `mousePressed()` event. Then keep a variable in your class (lets say "clickCounter") that you increment every time the event is generated.
2. Then you will need to handle the `mouseMoved()` event to know when the mouse is moving.

So now your logic in the `mouseMoved()` event can check if the variable is odd, which would indicate the mouse has just been clicked:

```
if (clickCounter % 2 == 1)
{
    add your logic here
}
```

Or you could keep a boolean variable that you toggle off/on for every mouse click.